# How different structure (Resistor, Diode, and Transistor) can be model in IC?

Tags: resistors, integrated-circuit, npn, pnp

[image]

I found this image in the book "Practical Electronics for Inventor".

I can partially understand what is happening in diode, and transistor. But how does the resistor works?

Comment: Note it gets more subtle than that too. The diode you are looking at is a PN junction diode which is a slab of P and N silicon. But there are also Schottky diodes which is a metal slab and N-silicon. But if metal and silicon against each other can make a diode, then why don't the aluminum traces in your drawing form Schottky diodes everywhere? And how do you connect pins and gold bonding wires to the silicon die for that matter?

Comment: What is not being shown is Ohmic contacts. What you make isn't just determined by what the arrangement of metal and silicon. The type and degree of doping, as well as how the interface is prepared between the materials also determines what device you end up with.

Answer (score 0):

Some info here: 
[Lingkai Kong, *Lecture 2: CMOS Technology and Passive Devices*, EECS240 – Spring 2013, UC Berkeley](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/icdesign/ee240_sp13/lectures/Lecture02_Passives_2up.pdf) 
particularly around page 8.

The diffusion doped silicon has fairly modest resistivity, therefore a long thin strip of it has useful resistance (10s to 10ks of ohms).

Larger value resistors are usually made as a "pinch" structure, or a JFET structure (these have the downside of much looser tolerances, and/or nonlinearity), while lower values might use metal layers.